# Async & await multiple tasks in a loop, how to return single Task

Tags: loops, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, entity-framework-6

This example is with entity framework, but the question is more about how to `await` multiple `async` tasks within a loop. Say I have the following method on a custom `DbContext` class:

```cs
public async Task DiscardChangesAsync()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x != null))
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                await entry.ReloadAsync(); // <-- only async method
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above compiles and runs, but I'm not sure how efficient it is. For example, if the context contains 10 deleted entity entries, the thread stops and waits at each `ReloadAsync` before it continues the loop, right? Is there any way to let the loop execution continue, and return a new `Task` that won't complete until all 10 of the `ReloadAsync` calls have completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question strictly:

```cs
public Task DiscardChangesAsync()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x != null))
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                tasks.Add(entry.ReloadAsync());
                break;
        }
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

May be more efficient, though, to let EF handle reloading all of them at once:

```cs
public Task DiscardChangesAsync()
{
    List<DbEntityEntry> deleted = new List<DbEntityEntry>();

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x != null))
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                deleted.Add(entry);
                break;
        }
    }

    return ctx.RefreshAsync(RefreshMode.StoreWins, deleted);
}
```

Comment: I would have to cast `this` to `IObjectContextAdapter` in order to invoke `RefreshAsync`. Any issues there? Wonder why they omitted that method from `DbContext`..? Also, shouldn't the argument be `RefreshMode.StoreWins` instead of `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues`?

Comment: Turns out the second more efficient option fails at runtime. After casting the `DbContext` to an `IObjectContextAdapter` and using `RefreshMode.StoreWins` to get it to compile, my integration test fails with "The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager." The first strict answer does not fail the integration test though.

Comment: Ahh, I gave you a LINQ to SQL `RefreshMode`. You are correct `RefreshMode.StoreWins` is the right one.

Comment: I thought I'd done that to undelete entities before but I guess I was mistaken.